# ImageMagick: how to achieve low memory usage while resizing a large number of image files?

Tags: linux, image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I would like to resize a large number (about 5200) of image files (PPM format, each 5 MB in size) and save them to PNG format using `convert`.

**Short version:**

`convert` blows up 24 GB of memory although I use the syntax that tells `convert` to process image files consecutively.

**Long version:**

Regarding more than 25 GB of image data, I figure I should not process all files simultaneously. I searched the ImageMagick documentation about how to process image files consecutively and I [found](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php):

> It is faster and less resource intensive to resize each image it is
>   read:
>
> `$ convert '*.jpg[120x120]' thumbnail%03d.png`

Also, [the tutorial states](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/):

> For example instead of...
>
> `montage '*.tiff'  -geometry 100x100+5+5 -frame 4  index.jpg`
>
> which reads all the tiff files in first, then resizes them. You can
>   instead do...
>
> `montage '*.tiff[100x100]'  -geometry 100x100+5+5 -frame 4  index.jpg`
>
> This will read each image in, and resize them, before proceeding to
>   the next image. Resulting in far less memory usage, and possibly
>   prevent disk swapping (thrashing), when memory limits are reached.

**Hence, this is what I am doing:**

```
$ convert '*.ppm[1280x1280]' pngs/%05d.png
```

According to the docs, it should treat each image file one by one: read, resize, write. I am doing this on a machine with 12 real cores and 24 GB of RAM. However, during the first two minutes, the memory usage of the `convert` process grows to about 96 %. It stays there a while. CPU usage is at maximum. A bit longer and the process dies, just saying:

> Killed

At this point, no output files have been produced. I am on Ubuntu 10.04 and `convert --version` says:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.5.7-8 2012-08-17 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

It looks like `convert` tries to read all data before starting the conversion. So either there is a bug in `convert`, an issue with the documentation or I did not read the documentation properly.

What is wrong? How can I achieve low memory usage while resizing this large number of image files?

BTW: a quick solution would be to just loop over the files using the shell and invoke `convert` for each file independently. But I'd like to understand how to achieve the same with pure ImageMagick.

Thanks!

Comment: If you try something like 
`find . -name "*.ppm" -exec convert '{}[1280x1280]'  pngs/%05d.png \;` does this works ?
`find -exec` will list all the files and for each of them executes the command given in argument.

Comment: @epingle: In principle this works (as I said in the last part of my question). Doing something like that also is my temporary solution. Still, it also has to (should) work with pure ImageMagick. (Note that your particular solution would not work, as the file counter `%05d` would always be zero).

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't see the end of your message or that the %05d was a counter for you

Comment: I would use netpbm and gnu make (-j12). If netpbm is ok for you, I'll copy/paste my working makefile as example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without having direct access to your system it's really hard to help you debugging this.

But you can do three things to help yourself narrowing down this problem:

1. Add `-monitor` as the first commandline argument to see more details about what's going on.
2. (Optionally) add `-debug all -log "domain: %d  +++ event: %e  +++ function: %f  +++ line: %l  +++ module: %m  +++ processID: %p  +++ realCPUtime: %r  +++ wallclocktime: %t  +++ userCPUtime: %u \n\r"`
3. Temporarily, don't use '*.ppm[1280x1280]' as an argument, but use 'a*.ppm[1280x1280]' instead. The purpose is to limit your wildcard expansion (or some other suitable way to achieve the same) to only a few matches, instead of all possible matches.

If you do '2.' you'll need to do '3.' as well otherwise you'll be overwhelmed by the mass of output. (Also your system does seem to not be able to process the full wildcard anyway without having to kill the process...)

If you do not find a solution, then...

1. ...register a username at [**the official ImageMagick bug report forum**](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=3).
2. ...report your problem there to see if *they* can help you (these guys are rather friendly and responsive if you ask politely).

Answer (score 3):

Got the same issue, it seems **it's because ImageMagick create temporary files into the /tmp directory**, which is often mounted as a tmpfs.

Just move your tmp somewhere else.

*For example:*

- create a "tmp" directory on a big external drive

  `mkdir -m777 /media/huge_device/tmp`
- make sure the permissions are set to 777

  `chmod 777 /media/huge_device/tmp`
- as root, mount it in replacement to your /tmp

  `mount -o bind /media/huge_device/tmp /tmp`

*Note:* It should be possible to use with the TMP environment variable to do the same trick.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with GNU Parallel if you have 12 cores - something like this, which works very well. As it does only 12 images at a time, whilst still preserving your output file numbering, it only uses minimal RAM.

```
scene=0
for f in *.ppm; do
   echo "$f" $scene
   ((scene++))
done | parallel -j 12 --colsep ' ' --eta convert {1}[1280x1280] -scene {2} pngs/%05d.png
```

**Notes**

`-scene` lets you set the scene counter, which comes out in your `%05d` part.

`--eta` predicts when your job will be done (Estimated Arrival Time).

`-j 12` runs 12 jobs in parallel at a time.